# change stye div by option drop down in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I tried to do this code HTML/CSS/JavaScript

Have idea Div and options (01-02-03)

When i select option 01 will give me style css ex; shadow, than select option 02 will give me other style shadow

```
‹div id= card-shadow-control" style="width: 100px; border: 1px solid black; margin: auto;
padding: zOpx; text-align: center >Hello‹/div>
‹select id="choose!>
‹option value="ol" style= box-shadow: 0 4px 6px -1px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.1), 0 2px 4px -2px rgb (0 0 0 / 0.1) ; "›shadow01‹/option> option value="02"›shadow02‹/option)
<option value="03" style="box-shadow: 0 20px 25px -5px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.1, 0 8px 10px
- 6px
reb (0 0 0 / 0.1);">shadow03</option) </select>

<script>
function myFunction () {
var x = document. getElementById ("choose") .options [0] .text;
document. getElementById("card-shadow-control").innerHTML=x;} 
</script>
```

I tried to do that but not work

Comment: Your HTML is not working, would you modify it?

Comment: Hey, Modify JavaScript

Comment: Your HTML cannot be displayed correctly, how can I test your javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change CSS Box Shadow in the element, you should do that in the `.onchange` event. Take the value of the option and use it as a selector to get the `data-box-shadow` on the selected option element. Then, apply it in box-shadow style at `card-shadow-control`. Make sure your code looks like this :

```js
document.getElementById("choose").onchange = function() {
  var x = document.getElementById("choose").value;
  var option = document.querySelector(`option[value="${x}"]`);
  if(option.dataset.boxShadow) {
    document.getElementById("card-shadow-control").style.boxShadow = option.dataset.boxShadow;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("card-shadow-control").style.boxShadow = '';
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div id="card-shadow-control" style="width: 100px; border: 1px solid black; margin: auto;
padding: zOpx; text-align: center">Hello</div>

<select id="choose">
  <option value="01" data-box-shadow="0 4px 6px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), 0 2px 4px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)">shadow01</option>
  <option value="02" selected>shadow02</option>
  <option value="03" data-box-shadow="0 20px 25px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), 0 8px 10px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)">shadow03</option> 
</select>
```